# Wordpress > add_filter() : Allow Multiple Accounts with one user

Tags: wordpress, email, account

I d'ont know why it doesn't work. Could you help me?

```
add_filter('pre_user_email', 'skip_email_exist');
function skip_email_exist($user_email){
    define( 'WP_IMPORTING', 'SKIP_EMAIL_EXIST' );
    return $user_email;
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The code syntax is correct so the code is obviously working, just not as intended. But for us to help you with that, you will need to provide more information. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't think the `pre_user_email` filter/hook does what you think it does. The purpose of this is only to filter the email address the user entered for characters you don't want in there (trimming extra white space of the ends, filtering of characters not allowed in email address name or domain parts, that kind of stuff) - but it is _not_ responsible for checking whether an account with that email already exists. And I am pretty sure that WordPress will have the email column in its user table set to UNIQUE, so that even if you tried and circumvent any script-side checks, [...]

Comment: [...] the database itself will still quit this with an error. In that case what you want won't be possible without modifying the database structure in that regard. Plus, since users can login using either their user name or email address, even that part might fail if the password entered gets checked against the "wrong" one in the database. You have given no reason for why you would need this - but I think it is a very bad idea to begin with.